# Cloning HTML5 elements and events with jQuery on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to clone a HTML5 element with jQuery 1.8.1, but [this example jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ogebeg/13/edit) fails on IE<9 (element is not cloned)

Code (simplified)

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <section>My section</section>
  <button>Clone section</button>
  ...

  <script>
  var section = $('section');
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var clone = section.clone(true);
    $(clone).insertAfter($('section:last'));
  }); 

  $('section').on('click', function() {
     alert('hey, I am a section');
  }); 
  </script>

</body>
```

This is, of course, a simplified demo. In my real code I have many nested elements with several events:

**My questions**

1. is this a bug of jQuery or did I miss something in my code?
2. since I'm also cloning the events associated with nodes, which elegant alternative could I use to reproduce the same behaviour of `clone()` also on IE<9 ?

So far the only workaround I've found is to copy all the nodes via `html()`, append them via `append()` and refactor my code taking advantage of **event delegation** for events associated to those nodes, like so

```
  $('body').on('click', 'section', function() {
     alert('hey, I am a section');
  });
```

But I'm opened to different ideas: could I use a more elegant/performant/easier/faster approach ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey fabrizio, I don't know if this I the actual problem or not but several of my coworkers just ran into some issues with 1.8.1 running document . ready before the document actually is ready causing scripts to not run. This is a known issue and there is a post on jquery's website about it (sorry I lost the link). There may be some workaround using delays or something similar to help you test this. I good luck :)

Comment: hi Zachary, I don't think this is related on a specific jQuery version... that code is not working also on jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel The issue with the DOM Ready handler was in 1.8 with IE9/10, do you mean 1.8.1 has even more serious problems?

Comment: (side note: I'm on mobile right now which is why I can't play with your code)... Yes, I 1.8.1 is having big problems with that... It actually caused one of our scripts to blow up, and thus blew up the rest as well. Is perhaps the article. I saw was for 1.8.. I didn't post about it on jquery's Site because I thought the article was for 1.8.1

Comment: I believe IE7/8 don't support HTML5, and therefore don't understand `section`. If you're not already using some kind of shim/library to deal with that, try doing so. If you are already using it, then there might still be an issue with how jQuery handles the clone for those kinds of elements, but it would help to know what library you're using.

Comment: jQuery works well with HTML5 elements on IE<9 if you append them via `append/appendTo/insertAfter/after...`. The problem is specifically `clone()`

Comment: Another thing that could be an issue is if the clone hasn't finished before the selector looks for sections. You could try testing with a `.promise().done()`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Sure. See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792995/html-5-time-tag-not-recognized-by-ie8-when-cloning) where the answer is similar to my comment (and apparently solved the issue).

Comment: Unfortunately not :(  http://jsbin.com/ogebeg/13/edit

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Funny stuff. JSBin seems to add defer attributes to all scripts, and this messes up the parsing. Here's an equivalent jsfiddle, and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Hhxsg/

Comment: (I filed a JSBin issue: https://github.com/remy/jsbin/issues/334 )

Comment: well, so if you write this as solution I will mark it as accepted :) Anyway I tried your fiddle on two different IE8 (both original and emulated SO with WMvare): on the emulated browser it still doesn't work :( . Thank you again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess after all the comments, I might as well add this as an answer: the problem seems to be that you need an html5 shim (like [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)), and it needs to be loaded before your HTML5 elements occur (lest the parser get confused). The [`defer` attributes JSBin automatically adds](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/issues/217) break this behaviour.

Without the shim, the elements get broken up. the DOM ends up looking like this:

```
<section/>
My section
</section/>
```

(as seen in the IE8 dev tools -- you've got to at least admire the creativity in interpretation that's at work here)

This breaks all the relevant selectors (hence why the text isn't green in the [JSBin item](http://jsbin.com/ogebeg/13/edit) you posted). The reason all the other calls (insert, append, etc.) were still working is that the html you were feeding those was the same (and would get mis-parsed in the same way).

The solution is forcing the shim to load completely before your elements occur, as seen in the [jsFiddle counterexample](http://jsfiddle.net/Hhxsg/) I posted.

Hopefully this solves your issue. I filed a [JSBin issue regarding the problems caused by the defer attributes](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/issues/334).

Update: this should be fixed in jsbin by now.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think the problem really is with `<section>` ,IE8 is unable to understand it, I have tried Cloning Button and the code runs smoothly :-)

I have tried changing your JavaScript to make it run on IE9:(NOT WORKING FOR < IE9)

```
<script>
  var section = $('section');
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var clone = section.clone(true);
    $(clone).insertBefore($('section:last'));  //CHANGE From insertAfter to InsertBefore
  }); 

  $('section').on('click', function() {
     alert('hey, I am a section');
  }); 
  </script>
```

Now it looks like working for IE9, and other browsers as well.

or if you are specific about placing newly clones Script would be changed as below :

```
var section = $('section');
var button = $('button')
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var clone = section.clone(true);
    console.log(clone);
  $(clone).insertBefore($('button'));
}); 
$('section').on('click', function() {
  alert('hey, I am a section');
});
```

Comment: The issue is with IE8 and below.